# Js движение блоков

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем добрый день,только за регистрировался на данном сайте,есть вопрос,в есть вопрос относительно js Есть блок на который при наведении вылезает другой блок если убрать курсор то уезжает
проблема след: в блоке есть другие div с текстом если на них навести и убрать мышь то действия скрипта повторяться,а мне это не нужно,как исправить не подскажите

Comment: извиняюсь при скройлинге блок исчезает как это реализовать что бы при скройлинге внутри блока другой блок не исчезал

Comment: покажите свой код

Comment: как отвечать на этом сайте?

Comment: Посмотрите здесь. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help Если вопрос будет детально  изложен и с фрагментом кода по сути, вы найдёте ответ довольно быстро.